# Content Taxonomy along with Conditional Fields

Tags: drupal, conditional-statements, taxonomy, drupal-fields

I'm still young at Drupal.So please correct me wherever needed.

I have a requirement wherein I want my content type to have my own fields (achieved with CCK), then I want one of the fields to be a selectable drop down and each drop down value should actually categorize them so that each type can come on separate page. This I managed with taxonomy. And in addition to these,I wanted some other fields in the same content type to be dependent on a particular value in the drop down. So I used conditional fields. And in order to use taxonomy term as field,I used content taxonomy. But unfortunately, conditional fields doesn't see the content taxonomy drop down (it works perfectly well if its a normal non-taxonomy drop down).

So basically,

1. I want content to be separated (i.e.
   on different pages) on the basis of
   a value selected from drop down.
2. And if a particular value is
   selected from drop down, few other
   fields should become visible.

How am I to incorporate these things? Am I on the right track or completely off track?
I am using Drupal 6.14. :)
Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, but the Conditional Fields is still in beta, so bugs/missing features are to be expected. Also, Content Taxonomy is a bit special compared to other CCK modules, as it only provides a replacement of the taxonomy fields on node edit forms, but is not present/active during node rendering.

That said, your Problem is already filed as a feature request in [the issue queue of the conditional fields module](http://drupal.org/project/issues/search/conditional_fields?status[]=8&status[]=13&status[]=14), and there are some [patches available and discussed](http://drupal.org/node/250748) to solve it - so you might want to check out that thread.

Comment: "Content Taxonomy is a bit special compared to other CCK modules, as it only provides a replacement of the taxonomy fields on node edit forms, but is not present/active during node rendering."
You completely changed my view to look at content taxonomy! That is SO correct! I'll definitely try the D6 patches discussed in the issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure how you require the 'different pages' part to work, but if everything else works with a non-taxonomy dropdown - and you don't have time for the issues with Conditional Fields to get shaken out - then you may be able to set up a *View* page that filters on the value of the CCK node.

Comment: Well finally the solution to my problem was combination of taxonomy,conditional fields & most importantly,views. I decided not to use content taxonomy. Oh yes, and taxonomy defaults came in handy for some content types. Thank you all! :)